# Geometric sequence in bash

Tags: bash

Hello i working on bash geometric sequence, here is my code. What i'm doing wroing ?

```
function geometric {
    a1=$1;
    q=$2;
    n=$3;

    echo "$a1";
    for ((i=1; i<n+1; i++))
    do
        echo $((a1*(q^(i-1))))
    done
}
```

Comment: would be better if you add some output with sample input passed to the function along with showing what part of output is wrong

Comment: The exponentiation operator in `bash` is `**`, not `^`. Just search for "exponentiation" in the manual.

Comment: What *are* you doing wrong? Why do you think something is wrong? What have you done to try to fix it?

Comment: This is a bad way to generate a geometric sequence in *any* language. Just multiply the previous term by `q` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The exponentiation operator in `bash` is `**` rather than `^`. The latter is actually the bitwise-or operator. So the simple solution would be to (after getting rid of the initial superfluous `echo`) modify the expression `echo` to be:

```
 echo $((a1*(q**(i-1))))
```

However, you *may* want to give some consideration to making it more readable, avoiding the use of complex expressions, along the lines of:

```
function geometric {
    ((val = $1))
    ((mult = $2))
    ((count = $3))

    while [[ ${count} -gt 0 ]] ; do
        echo ${val}
        ((val *= mult))
        ((count -= 1))
    done
}
```